# "Open with" equivalent on Mac

Tags: ms-office, software, defaults

I have a very simple problem and I thought the solution would be simple. However, I do not see any straightforward solution to this problem so far.

I have a CSV file and in Windows world you can always `Shift + Right Click` on this and it will give you option for `Open With` and you can view the same file in either Notepad++ or in Excel depending on your preference. On macOS I have a CSV file and that file is opened in Excel format no matter what I do. I am trying to view the file in Notepad without any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mac have right click / control click as well as drag and drop - are you just looking for those sort of one time deviations from the programmed connections?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to open a file with a specific program, you can right click the file and hover over the `Open With` menu item that appears.

First, find the file in Finder, then right click the file. From the top, the second option will be `Open With`. You can hover over that menu item to see a list of every app that the system knows can open that particular file.

At the very bottom of the menu containing the list of apps, there will be an item titled `Other...`. This allows you to choose any app on your Mac to open the file with.

Comment: If you don't have a two-button mouse to right-click with, you can use Control-click to get the "secondary click" function. You can also use the Mouse or Trackpad preferences (in System Preferences) to assign the secondary click function.

Comment: I use TextWrangler to deal with CSV files : and it can do unix line returns etc as well - ie the different csv formats...